# Using SDL library to play a raw sine wave generated using sinf function

Tags: audio, sdl, wave, trigonometry

I am trying to generate sound tones of various frequencies, by creating sample data using the sine function and playing using SDL.
I am using

```
buffer[sample] = 32767 * sinf( 2 * PI * sample * sound_frequency / 44100)
```

to generate a samples for a sound of frequency - sound_frequency at a sampling rate of 44100.
and got 44100 samples ie. a sample sound of 1 second and tried to play using SDL.
It is sounding fine when i tried to generate sample for sound_frequency of 2000Hz. But it also sounding fine when tried to generate sample for sound_frequency of 60000Hz. But i expected i should sound for 20-20000Hz only? 
Could you please help in finding the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot represent frequency higher than your sampling rate. Your sound will be distorted even with frequencies near the sampling rate. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions) is happening.

Comment: Even better: you cannot represent frequencies higher than [**half** your sampling rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).